# wildfly swarm deployment crash with java 9

Tags: java, java-9, wildfly-swarm

Packaging a hello world application generated by the wildfly swarm generator and built with Java9 crashes when deploying the application.
It seems that the reason is the swarm/undertow dependency to the `org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.4` which is not Java9 ready.

Is there a known workaround, or a known date when swarm will be ready for Java9?

The stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.JAXRSArchiveImpl.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchiveImpl.java:117)
at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.JAXRSArchiveImpl.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchiveImpl.java:96)
at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive.isJAXRS(JAXRSArchive.java:55)
at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.DefaultJAXRSWarDeploymentFactory.create(DefaultJAXRSWarDeploymentFactory.java:46)
at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.internal.DefaultJAXRSWarDeploymentFactory$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.create(Unknown Source)
org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.deployments.DefaultDeploymentCreator.createDefaultDeployment(DefaultDeploymentCreator.java:69)
```

Comment: WF Swarm currently is tied to JDK 8.

Once WF is updated to support JDK 9, we will look to follow suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class files in JDK 9 are v53.0 so you need ASM 6. ASM has always thrown IAE when encountering class files that are newer that it supports.

Comment: Thank you, also the [comment from Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449735/wildfly-swarm-deployment-crash-with-java-9#comment79860790_46449735) made everything clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

The `IllegalArgumentException` can be possibly caused by different class version when scanning the bytecode which in your case which is done by `org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.4`.

We faced  similar issue faced in [jetty.project#1758](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1758) which I'd to try and solve by building the jetty.project by myself but to eventually realize that `org.ow2.asm` would chain me back still.

---

The [latest available version of asm](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.ow2.asm%7Casm-all%7C6.0_BETA%7Cjar) on maven is :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
   <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
   <version>6.0_BETA</version>
</dependency>
```

In case of jetty (*and probably swarm as well*) they were not able to integrate this as `6.0_BETA` is not a valid *OSGI version number*:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid range
>   `"[6.0_BETA,6.0_BETA]"`: invalid version `"6.0_BETA"`: non-numeric
>   `"0_BETA"`

Related to the above a [read to how jetty tried solving it](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/pull/1801).

There is already a [tracker](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=317782&group_id=23&atid=100023) to the `ow2.asm` invalid version bug which you can follow.